# what is the reference for timing calculations in linux

Tags: c, linux, timer, kernel

I want to clarify about timers in linux, how they are behaving?
I know in micro-controllers the timers/counters we use the reference, timing of machine instruction to execute.so there we could make it loop for how much time we need sleep/timer/counter.

But in linux where & how it will take the reference that if i use sleep(5), exactly 5 seconds are elapsed.If any one know please clarify me kindly.

Comment: If you [read the `sleep` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) you will see that it sleeps until the number of seconds have passed. In other words it will sleep *at least* five second, but can sleep a little longer (depending on timer resolution and precision and such).

Comment: thanks for reply @JoachimPileborg , but my clarification is about how the kernel will able to calculate that 5 seconds timing period.

Comment: The same way as you already know? There are timers and counters in the hardware (on the CPU) that the kernel utilizes, and that can generate interrupts on specific intervals. A major difference between a "micro-controller" and an Intel i7 CPU is mostly the scale: One is small and the other is all but small.

Comment: can i get a code snippet in kernel for that (some example), that will be more helpful. Thanks @JoachimPileborg

Comment: There are *tens of millions* of lines of code in the kernel. Download the source yourself, find the architecture directory you are wondering about, and go look.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i have read in internet that for timing reference there will be a variable is defined in,kernel i.e **jiffies**. which is define in <linux/jiffies.h>. so the jiffies variable is updated by the timer interrupts. what is your opinion about this **jiffies** variable?

Answer (score 1):

Every operating system kernel (that I know of) has a whole machine independent framework for timers. This is pretty much one of the most central things a kernel must have because we need timers for everything, process scheduling, dealing with hardware errors, select/poll timeouts, network protocols, etc. At any point in time your kernel has dozens, if not thousands of timers waiting to be executed at some point in the future. Most of them will be canceled and never executed.

The simplest framework that pretty much everyone uses sets up one of the many clocks in a machine to generate an interrupt at a set interval. 100Hz is the most common, Windows (at least in the past) sets it to 64Hz (but it can be changed by any application), some systems experimented with 1024Hz. The timer interrupt fires and the interrupt handler checks if there's anything queued up to do at that time and if there is, it is executed. There has been some work for Linux to improve this so that we can get shorter or longer intervals than 10ms depending on the next scheduled timer, both to improve the precision of the timers and to save power, but in general it works as described above.

If I understand your question correctly, you think that there is something that measures how much certain sequence of instructions takes and then loops until some amount of time passes. This is something that is almost never done because it wastes power and it blocks anything else from running at the same time and is also quite unreliable. It is still done in modern kernels, but very rarely and only when high precision is required when talking to really, really stupid hardware. Last time I had to do it was 17 years ago to talk to some ethernet controller where you had to manually implement MII by bit-banging in software, it was terrible and hung the system for quite a long time every time you (un-)plugged an ethernet cable. Nobody builds hardware that requires this anymore because it really ruins the performance of modern systems.

So in your question, sleep(5) will be implemented by registering a function in the timer framework to be called in 5 seconds from now and then putting the process to sleep. 5 seconds later the timer fires and the process gets awakened again.